# Chart JS Custom tooltips with % and label for X and Y axles

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I can't seem to find a good enough answer to this problem.

I'm trying to figure out how to customise the tooltip label for both x and y axles,

Using this code i was able to customise the yLabel for each tooltip:

```html
    options: {
    
    tooltips: {
        callbacks: {
            label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
                return "Energi, Vatten och Återvinning: " + Number(tooltipItem.yLabel).toFixed(0).replace(/./g, function(c, i, a) {
                    return i > 0 && c !== "." && (a.length - i) % 3 === 0 ? "," + c : c;
                });
            }
        }
    },
```

[tooltip as shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mgm8B.png)

As my JS knowledge is limited, i can't seem to be able to modify the script into displaying a percentage sign after the value, as well as displaying the label for the x axle as well.

Answer (score 0):

You might be pulling my leg here because nothing fancy is needed, just add + " %" at the end of label function return:

```html
    options: {
    
    tooltips: {
        callbacks: {
            label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
                return "Energi, Vatten och Återvinning: " + Number(tooltipItem.yLabel).toFixed(0).replace(/./g, function(c, i, a) {
                    return i > 0 && c !== "." && (a.length - i) % 3 === 0 ? "," + c : c;
                })+ " %";
            }
        }
    },
```

Also, it seems to me your entire function can at least be reduced to:

```html
    options: {
    
    tooltips: {
        callbacks: {
            label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
                return "Energi, Vatten och Återvinning: " +  Number(tooltipItem.yLabel).toFixed(0)+ " %";
            }
        }
    },
```

Comment: Thanks for the percentage answer, that was quite rookie mistake to make, but the question relating to the x axle label hasn't been answered, which is more or less the main problem

Comment: Well if you are thinking about the xLabel name in the tooltip, that can be configured using the title callback:
https://jsfiddle.net/6kya3Ltu/
You might have to customize the function to fit your graph type but this is in essence how you can do that.